# Expo-Notifications requestPermissionsAsync() is giving error

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, android-permissions, expo-notifications

When i call requestPermissionsAsync i got this error:

Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method requestPermissionsAsync on module ExpoNotificationPermissionsModule: String resource ID #0xffffffff
Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method requestPermissionsAsync on module ExpoNotificationPermissionsModule: String resource ID #0xffffffff
at construct (native)
at apply (native)
at _construct (http://192.168.10.5:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:4486:28)
at Wrapper (http://192.168.10.5:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:4448:25)
at construct (native)
at _createSuperInternal (http://192.168.10.5:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:124526:322)
at call (native)
at CodedError (http://192.168.10.5:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:124539:26)

Code:

```
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
let notificationCounter = 0;
export async function setDietNotification() {
  const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
  let finalStatus = existingStatus;
  if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
    const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
    finalStatus = status;
  }
  if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
    console.log("Notification permission not granted");
    return;
  }
  const notificationId = `diet-${Date.now()}-${notificationCounter}`;
  notificationCounter++;
  const notificationRequest = await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
    identifier: notificationId,
    content: {
      title: "You've got mail! ",
      body: "Here is the notification body",
      data: { dietIndex: 1 },
      vibrate: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      sound: "default",
      color: "yellow",
    },
    trigger: { seconds: 2 }, // Convert milliseconds to seconds
 
  });

  Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener((response) => {
    if (response.notification.request.identifier === notificationId) {
      if (screenToNavigate) {
        consol.log("screenToNavigate")
        });
      }
      console.log("herer");
    }
  });

  return notificationRequest;
}
```

i have tried it many times clearing cashe, updating expo cli, reinstalling node module but nothing is working. can someone please help me fix that